# In CQ5, how to access login credentials saved in JCR

Tags: authentication, components, jcr, aem

i am working on CQ5. I have implemented the form components of CQ5 and able to access the contents saved in JCR (Java Content Repository).
Currently i am implementing the CQ5 default Login component. I have made a Login page and Registration page. Registration page has some users entries like firstname, lastname, username, email and password etc. Hence, the Login should use the entries of users in registration table in JCR but i am unable to do so.

Please help me to solve the problem. How to implement login component using JCR i.e to login with the data saved in JCR . 
Or it can be done by using external database.

Thanks

Komal

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the OOTB login component under CQ foundation components? Does that help?
Also what exactly are you doing in Registration? If you are creating CQ5 users using the registration details, then the default login component should do for the most part.
From your question it seems you might not be creating a user while registering. If you are maintaining a separate table of sorts for the registered users then you would accordingly need to change the login component logic to utilize your table.